# Resharper string.format shortcut

Tags: c#, resharper

I often find myself writing

```
var message = "Hello {0}";
```

and then going back and typing in

```
var message = string.Format("Hello {0}", world);
```

It would be nice if as I were typing the string, when I put the " at the end, resharper figured out there was a parameter in the string and immediately surrounded the string with the string.Format method and put the cursor at the first argument.

Is there a straightforward way to do this? I'm using Resharper 6.1

Comment: Instead of typing `{0}`, just use `alt+enter` and select the R# option of `Add new format item and proper argument`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just type it in dumber:

```
 "Hello " + world
```

<kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, done<sup>1</sup>:

```
 string.Format("Hello {0}", world);
```

Obviously, this also works when the whole thing is much more complex. I know it will strip useless calls to `.ToString()`, and I suspect it will automatically lift any format expressions, like

```
 int i = 42;
 "i = " + i.ToString("X2");
```

<kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
 string.Format("i = {0:X2}", i);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> If you're unlucky/the surrounding code contains many things that trigger Resharper suggestions(?) you *might have to position the cursor over one of the `+` operators*

Comment: You can just type the string `"Hello "` and then, while the cursor is still inside the quotes, use R# `Alt+Enter` > `Enter` which will select the R# option of `Add new format item and proper argument`. R# will take care of the cursor placement before and after.

Comment: @MetroSmurf: Ah can you confirm that is R# 6.x stuff? I've seen the options with format strings have been improved, but I haven't exercised them all that much yet :)

Comment: yes, this works with R#6. I believe it was introduced in v6 as well. Probably the most used new feature I've made use of with R#6 (sad, I know :)

Comment: @MetroSmurf: caller graph and value origin inspection FTW, in my opinion. Thanks for the addition!

Answer (score 3):

**Shameless plug**

I've also tried to formulate an approach to make string format creation easier, and what I came up with is *string splicing* a-la PHP:

[image]

This is part of a ReSharper plug-in that you can find [here](http://activemesa.com/r2p).

Answer (score 2):

I ended up writing an extension method for strings named `FormatWith(arg0, ar1...)` because of this. Then I found that the [Humanizer](https://github.com/MehdiK/Humanizer) library did the same exact thing. Add the Humanizer NuGet package and now you'll be able to write `"Heres my formatted string on the {0}st try!".FormatWith(1)"` with hopefully less bouncing around. If you have ReSharper and like that it highlights the matching placemarkers with the parameter, install the [Humanizer Annotations R# Extension](https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/Humanizer.Annotations/) and you'll get them back.

Answer (score 1):

You can *almost* do this with a Visual Studio snippet (i.e. without ReSharper).

Save the following as a file with a `.snippet` extension.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <Header>
        <Title>string format</Title>
        <Author>Matthew Strawbridge</Author>
        <Description>Wraps the selected text with string.Format</Description>
        <SnippetTypes>
            <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
        </SnippetTypes>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
        <Declarations>
            <Literal>
                <ID>variable</ID>
                <Default>value</Default>
            </Literal>
        </Declarations>
        <Code Language="CSharp">
            <![CDATA[string.Format($selected$, $variable$);]]>
        </Code>
    </Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
```

Then you can load it via **Tools | Code Snippets Manager | Import**.

Once the snippet is available, you can type

```
var message = "Hello {0}"
```

but you'd have to select the string and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and select the snippet name to apply it. This would generate

```
var message = string.Format("Hello {0}", value);
```

with the `value` part selected for editing.

**Edit:** There's also a [Snippet Designer extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/B08B0375-139E-41D7-AF9B-FAEE50F68392) that makes working with snippets easier.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate to Matthew's visual studio code snippet. This snippet asks for the variable name but defaults to message which is optional an the only thing required is the variable name. HTH

Looks like:

```
var message = string.Format( "abc {0}", variable );
```

as the default (the abc {0} was the highlighted text)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>String Format</Title>
      <Author>OmegaMan</Author>
      <Description>Surrounded text gets format</Description>
      <HelpUrl></HelpUrl>
      <SnippetTypes />
      <Keywords />
      <Shortcut>#SF</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <References />
      <Imports />
      <Declarations>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>name</ID>
          <Type></Type>
          <ToolTip>What the variable name should be.</ToolTip>
          <Default>message</Default>
          <Function></Function>
        </Literal>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>Vars</ID>
          <Type></Type>
          <ToolTip>The target variable for format.</ToolTip>
          <Default>variable</Default>
          <Function></Function>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="csharp" Kind="" Delimiter="$"><![CDATA[var $name$ = string.Format($selected$, $Vars$);$end$ ]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```