# Batch-convert C# code to use String.Format

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resharper string.format shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674705/resharper-string-format-shortcut)

In our large code base, unfortunately there are a lot of statements like this:

```
MessageBox.Show("Hello, " + userName + "!");
```

Obviously, this would be better to facilitate String externalisation:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Hello, {0}!", userName));
```

Is there any tool that can automate this job (convert string concatenations to String.Format)?

If not, I figure it would be necessary to find a parser that constructs a syntax tree for a given C# source file, find expressions that do string concatenations in this tree (does not seem easy) and convert the found occurences?

**EDIT**: DevExpress CodeRush does exactly what I want - pretty cool. But unfortunately it only works on the current source file and I have to click every occurence (or so it seems). I would like to do the operation on all of my source files (like with 'Replace all').

Comment: Could ReSharper do something like this?

Comment: I don't see how this is going to help you with internationalization. Only pulling your strings from a resource file will do that.

Comment: James, you are right - but before moving (existing) the strings in a resource file, I need to convert my "+" string concatenations (containing multiple strings) to a single format string.

Comment: I do not think this is a duplicate as I ask for a solution that can be used for batch processing.

Comment: I vote for reopening this question. It's by no means a duplicate.

Comment: I agree with @DennisTraub. There is no reason to assume that the developer has Resharper or CodeRush installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [DevExpress CodeRush](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/). It allows to easily find and refactor these issues. Though I don't know if you can automate the refactoring. [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) has a similar feature.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I am downloading CodeRush at the moment to give it a try. Would be great if it had a "semi-automatic" mode.

Comment: This does exactly what I want; but unfortunately I do not find a way to do it automatically for all my source files. Will contact DevExpress support regarding this issue.

Comment: The guys at DevExpress will implement this in a future release. http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S39455.aspx

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper does support this kind of action, by pressing <kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Read more about this here:
[Resharper string.format shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674705/resharper-string-format-shortcut)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have tools, a simple Replace All in Visual Studio should do it.

Find:

```
"([^"]*)"\s*\+\s*(:i)
```

Replace by:

```
String.Format("\1#{0}", \2)
```

Unfortunately I don't have access to Visual Studio now to test these expressions. You may have to use `:b` instead of `\s` in the "find" expression.

Comment: Think I'd do a Find Next/Replace if doing something like this.  Trust, but verify.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This really is a nice idea, but it won't work if there are multiple concatenations on the same line (which I have to admit we have got).

Comment: @WonkotheSane I normally use the option to "Keep changed files open" to be able to verify the results. Find Next/Replace wouldn't be feasible with thousands of replacements, but it would be easy to inspect some random files afterwards.